# When Twitter gets sold, do pre-purchase shareholders need to do anything?

Tags: united-states, stock-markets, merger-and-acquisition

Twitter is currently publicly traded, but once Elon Musk buys it, it'll go private.

Do current Twitter shareholders need to place sell orders so Musk can buy their shares?

Comment: What about short call and short put options that are expiring in March /June 2023 ?

Comment: @puzzled maybe you could ask that separately? It's an interesting question, but I think it could be better answered separately.

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/153362/ just posted

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Twitter stockholders will not be required to issue orders for Elon to purchase their shares.

Because the company's shares will no longer be traded publicly, the company will be delisted from the public exchange where they were previously traded, and stakeholders will be unable to trade them. Instead, each shareholder will receive $54.20 in cash for each share of Twitter stock owned.

Reference:https://mywallst.com/blog/what-will-happen-to-my-twitter-shares-when-they-go-private