# What happens to short PUT and short Call options on acquisitions. e.g Twitter

Tags: united-states, stocks, options, merger-and-acquisition

Currently Twitter is being [acquired](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acquisition_of_Twitter_by_Elon_Musk) by Elon Musk. As now the deal is likely to go ahead. What happens to the seller of Call options ( suppose some one has sold call for $60 strike expiring in June 2023), or seller of PUT options ( like someone sold PUT of $30 Strike for expiring in June 2023). Both in the money or out of the money short positions.

Comment: It's more than "likely to go ahead" -- it closed yesterday.

Comment: @barmar yes you are right, it is my first time experiencing merger acquisition on a stock that I owned, I still see shares in my brokerage along with short call option. I guess money will hit my brokerage on Saturday (10/29/2022) .

Comment: not yet ( (10/29/2022) any transaction for sale of twitter in my brokerage account , for position it changed from symbol TWTR to 90184L102 . I now look forward to see it on Monday

Answer (score 7):

In a cash buyout like this, options that are out-of-the-money are terminated. Options that are in-the-money are settled for cash, with the option seller paying the option holder the difference between the buyout price and the strike price.

In your example, both of the options would be worthless with an acquisition price of $54.20, but if one were short CALL options at $30, then they would be obligated to pay the option holder $24.20 per share.  If one were short a PUT option at $60 they would be required to pay $5.80.

Comment: @puzzled correct - I updated my answer

Comment: What if Elon re-publicizes Twitter before June 2023?

Comment: The options are settled at the time of the sale, not at their expiry. If it goes public again after the sale, it would be a new listing; the old options will still be gone.

Comment: @d-stanley thanks, I am slightly updating my question as it relates to both in the money and out of the money short options.

Comment: The options would settle at the time  they expiry.  This means that if I was short calls on twitter with a strike of 60 and expiration in 2023 I do not have to pay income tax on my gain until next year.  If it goes public again after the sale, it would be a new listing which would not effect.

Comment: @puzzled I address both OTM and ITM options in my answer.  Out-of-the-money options are just cancelled (no payment).

Comment: @bob Thanks yes it looks like that the out of money Call that I have for 2023 June will settle in 2023 and hence taxed in 2024.

Comment: @bob PUT and Call that were out of money both are expired as on Nov 18, 2022 even though they were supposed to be expired in 2023